# Checking if a Linked list is Empty in C

Tags: c, list, struct

I have a simple linked list (Which I'm given for a assignment), and I'm trying to check if it's empty (It has no header node), but my implementation doesn't seem to work.

I have the .c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "test.h"

int main(void) {
    List * node;
    node = NULL;

    node = malloc(sizeof(List));

    addToList(node);
    return 0;
}

void addToList(List * node) {
    if(node == NULL) {
        node->value = 3;
        node->next = NULL;
    }
    else {
        //add to end of the list:

        List * temp = malloc(sizeof(List));
        temp->value = 4;

        while(node->next != NULL) 
            node = node->next;

        node->next = temp;
        temp->next = NULL;
    }

}
```

And the Linked list in the struct (In the .h file)

```
typedef struct List {
    int value;
    List * next;
}List;
```

However, the if statement never executes, even though the list is empty. The struct I'm given doesn't have a header node(I can't change it), so how would I go about fixing this?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: By doing the malloc, your node is no longer NULL (assuming malloc succeeded to allocate the memory).  That is why you never hit the 'if' statement.  As a side note, you should always verify that malloc succeeded.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  The interface design of `addToList()` is fundamentally broken. With kludgy code initializing the `node` in `main()`, you could get it to work, sort of, but you should be able to choose which values are added to the list, not being stuck with `3` and `4` as the only options. There are many questions about lists in C on Stack Overflow which will show you how to do it right. Amongst other problems, if the memory allocation in `main()` fails, your code in `addToList()` will crash when it dereferences the null pointer. Fortunately, you're unlikely to ever encounter that.

Comment: However, the `node` allocated in `main()` is not guaranteed to have cleanly initialized memory — it could be any old garbage — so tracking through 'the list' that it points at is a recipe for disaster.  You might be lucky and by pure chance your implementation of `malloc()` might be returning zeroed memory (mainly because it hasn't been used for anything else, yet), but you can't afford to rely on that.

Comment: Are you sure this compiled correctly? It doesn't for me and I get noticeable errors. Which compiler did you use?

Comment: @Rob: it'll compile if you use a C++-ish compiler, but you're right — the structure definition can't be compiled in pure C because there is no type name `List` until after the `typedef` is complete.

Comment: Yup, that too … and then the interface design … problems …

Comment: Yeah it compiles with another typedef/ struct * List in the struct.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I deleted my comment cause it essentially said what you did. Forward references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in addToList

```
node == NULL
```

should be

```
node->next == NULL
```

then you'll also need to insure that function isn't given a null pointer.
Currently you are providing a valid pointer the function and so it is never `== NULL`

See:

```
node = malloc(sizeof(List));
addToList(node);
```

here node is assigned a pointer to a List and provided to addToList.

I suspect what you are really looking for doesn't include that if/else at all and should look something like this (**NOTE**: You must initialize your list node by hand before calling this function. malloc just gives you a pointer to garbage).

```
    //add to end of the list:       
    void addToList(List *node) {
         if (node == NULL) 
             return;
         List * temp = malloc(sizeof(List));
         temp->value = 4;

         while(node->next != NULL) 
             node = node->next;

         node->next = temp;
         temp->next = NULL;
    }
```

Comment: Okay, so if I set it to if(node->next == NULL), are we sure that the next time I call this function, the first if statement won't execute? Because, in the first if statement, I never touch the next pointer, so it's still NULL, afterwards, even though there is a node in it?

Comment: No you should get rid of that if statement all together. Your while already covers the end of the list case

Comment: just updated post to include what i think you're looking for

Comment: This requires an initialized node to get the list going.  And at the moment, that initialization has to be done by hand; there isn't a function to do it.

Comment: Just wondering how I would go about printing the list here, a simple while(node != NULL) { printf("%d",node->value); node = node->next; } . Doesn't seem to work here. It only ever seems to print the last element.

Answer (score 0):

As it was already said the problem is that at first you allocated a node

```
node = malloc(sizeof(List));
```

and it got the address of the allocated memory and only after that you called the function

```
addToList(node);
```

with this node as an argument.

As result this condition within the function

```
if(node == NULL) {
```

equal to false. node is not equal to NULL. It is equal to the address of the allocated memory.

It is much better when the function allocates itself each new node. However in this case you have to declare the function differently.

It and its call can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "test.h"

void addToList( List ** node, int value );
//              ^^^^^^^       ^^^^^^^^^ 

int main(void) 
{
    List * node  NULL;

    addToList( &node, 4 );

    return 0;
}

void addToList( List ** node, int value ) 
{
    while ( *node ) node = &( *node )->next;

    List * temp = malloc( sizeof( List ) );

    if ( temp != NULL )
    {
        temp->value = value;
        temp->next = NULL;

        *node = temp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The condition `node == NULL` is always false because, before accessing the `addToList` function, you write `node = malloc(sizeof(List))`.

Try remove this declaration and change the `if` statement in

```
if(node == NULL) {
    node = malloc(sizeof(List));
    node->value = 3;
    node->next = NULL;
}
```